# Android Application closes immediately -FCM

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, chat, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a chat app using Google cloud messaging. I have to migrate to FCM because of API Key. I used this tutorial: [GCM to FCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) but When I start the app, it closes immediately. 
   This is the part of Gcmintentservice. I didn't understand what I should make 
Gcmintentservice.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String key = intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
        switch (key) {
            case SUBSCRIBE:
                // subscribe to a topic
                String topic = intent.getStringExtra(TOPIC);
                subscribeToTopic(topic);
                break;
            case UNSUBSCRIBE:
                String topic1 = intent.getStringExtra(TOPIC);
                unsubscribeFromTopic(topic1);
                break;
            default:
                // if key is not specified, register with GCM
                registerGCM();
        }

    }
```

When I delete inside of onHandleIntent function, App is working and there is no error but instant messaging is not working.

Comment: Can you post the manifest file section of services and permissions.

Comment: The problem occurs on `GcmIntentService.java:49`. It's hard to say more than that it's a `NullPointerException`, which is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: It is the onHandleIntent function ` String key = intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
        switch (key) {
            case SUBSCRIBE:
                // subscribe to a topic
                String topic = intent.getStringExtra(TOPIC);
                subscribeToTopic(topic);
                break;
            case UNSUBSCRIBE:
                String topic1 = intent.getStringExtra(TOPIC);
                unsubscribeFromTopic(topic1);
                break;
            default:
                // if key is not specified, register with GCM
                registerGCM();
        }` @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" /> <service
            android:name=".gcm.MyFcmListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".gcm.GcmIntentService">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
@ADimaano